# tkinter custom button class **kwargs

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I'm trying to create a tkinter button class to add a resized image with text.

The button renders ok on the mainwindow as expected, but I cannot pass a command to the button.
The additional **kwargs to the `BTN_IMG_TXT` create errors with the original tk.button.
Hence I used following in class definition, which I believe the problematic part of the code.

```
def __init__(self, master, command, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Button.__init__(self,master=master, command=command)
```

Following is the full code for testing:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import  Image, ImageTk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x200")

def remove_item(event = None):
    print('Delete button pressed')  #debug

# custom button widget
class BTN_IMG_TXT(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, command, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self,master=master, command=command)
        self.fname = kwargs.get('fname')
        self.btn_txt = kwargs.get('btn_txt')
        img = Image.open(self.fname)
        image = img.resize((40,40), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # make static size
        self.photo1=  ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        b = tk.Button(self, text=self.btn_txt, image=self.photo1, 
                            compound="top", width=70, height=70,)
        b.pack(side="top")

frm_Main = tk.Frame(master=window, bg='#faeaea', borderwidth=2)
frm_Main.pack()
stp_btn = BTN_IMG_TXT(master=frm_Main,fname="stop_b.png",btn_txt='STOP',command=remove_item)
del_btn= BTN_IMG_TXT(master=frm_Main,fname="delete_b.png",btn_txt='DELETE', command=remove_item)
del_btn.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)
stp_btn.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tkinter `Button` can display text as well as image together** and by using `compound` parameter we can tell the button widget where to align the text with the image read more about the compound parameter in the [`config(**options)`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method) of Tkinter `Button`.

You are using a button inside a button that's why the command is not working because it is linking with the `BTN_IMG_TXT` class, not with the `b` which is inside of the class.

Here is what I did,

```py
# custom button widget
class BTN_IMG_TXT(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        # Merged both cnf and kw dictionaries.
        kw = tk._cnfmerge((kw, cnf)) 
        # make static size
        if kw.get('image'):
            img = Image.open(kw['image'])
            image = img.resize((40,40), Image.ANTIALIAS)  
            self.photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
            kw['image'] = self.photo1
        # Aligns the image on top and text under it
        kw['compound'] = kw.get('compound', 'top') 
        super().__init__(master=master, **kw)


frm_Main = tk.Frame(master=window, bg='#faeaea', borderwidth=2)
frm_Main.pack()
stp_btn = BTN_IMG_TXT(master=frm_Main, image="stop_b.png", text='STOP', command=remove_item)
del_btn= BTN_IMG_TXT(master=frm_Main, image="delete_b.png", text='DELETE', command=remove_item)
del_btn.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)
stp_btn.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)
```

I Hope, this solves your issue.

Comment: thanks. It solved the problem. Can you please elaborate what is `cnf` and `_cnfmerge`

Comment: [`_cnfmerge`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/69cdeeb93e0830004a495ed854022425b93b3f3e/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L96) is an inbuilt tkinter function which is used to merge `cnf` and `kw`. If in case you decide to provide arguments like `{'text': 'hello', 'bg': 'blue'}` to `cnf={}`, I merged `kw` and `cnf` so the code gets smaller and it won't give any errors. Though as long as you pass arguments like `text='hello', bg='blue'` then you don't need it.